# How to detect end of stream?

Tags: delphi, file, stream, position, eof

I have a DLL which outpus data to a stream. But it adds a postfix and prefix I don't want.
I can create a MemoryStream, let the DLL output the data and then trim it, but there can be a few GB of data, so I just want it to be saved directly to a file (FileStream).
I think the best solution is to create own Stream class.
So I made:

```
function TFileStream2.Write(const Buffer; Count: Integer): Longint;
```

where I check Position and if it is = 0 then I discard first few bytes from the Buffer.
This way I can trim the beginning of the file. But how can I detect end of stream so I can discard some bytes from the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the stream object is destroyed, simply trim off the final part of the file. You can do this by modifying the `Size` property.

Comment: But I think the bytes are already saved to disk. Can a file be shortened this way?